# Form works in internet explorer only when I hit F12 to bring up console

Tags: javascript, html

My form works only when I hit console in Internet Explorer. Works in all other browsers fine.

Here is the HTML: Why is it that when I bring up console everything works fine in IE?

```
        <div class="clubregister">
    <h2>
        Signup Form</h2>
    <p>
        We wont give your information to anyone. It is used to notify you of promotions occasionally and required for registration.</p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br />
    <input name="name" type="text" /><br />
    <label for="address">Address:</label><br />
    <input name="address" type="text" /><br />
    <label for="phone">Phone:</label><br />
    <input name="phone" type="text" /><br />
    <label for="email">Email:</label><br />
    <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
    <input class="button" name="submit" style="margin-top:10px;" type="button" value="Join Club" /></div>
```

Here is the Javascript: This is really weird how all this will work in IE when bring up console.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   /////////////////////////////////////////////
   //ARRAY DUMP FUNCTION
   function dump(a,b){var c="";if(!b)b=0;var d="";for(var e=0;e<b+1;e++)d+="          ";if(typeof a=="object"){for(var f in a){var g=a[f];if(typeof g=="object"){c+=d+"'"+f+"'   ...\n";c+=dump(g,b+1)}else{c+=d+"'"+f+"' => \""+g+'"\n'}}}else{c="===>"+a+"<===("+typeof  a+")"}return c}
  /////////////////////////////////////////////
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.clubregister  input[name="submit"]').click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
                    /*alert('This section is under construction, please contact us to get set up!\n Sorry for the inconvenience');return false;*/
        //CREATE ARRAY FROM FORM DATA SERIALIZED
        var $formData = $('.clubregister input[type="text"], .clubregister textarea').serializeArray();
        //PUSH ACTION TO ARRAY
        $formData.push({'name':'action','value':'registerForClub'});
        //SEND DATA TO HANDLER
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://torkliftcentralrv.com/club_register_handle.php',
            dataType:'json',
            async:false,
            data:$formData,
            success: function(data) {
                //console.log(dump(data));
                //CREATE MESSAGE
                var message = '';
                var consolemessage = '';
                //IF ERRORS
                if(typeof data['error'] !== 'undefined') {
                    //APPEND ERRORS TO MESSAGE
                    $.each( data['error'], function( index,data) {
                        message += (data + "\n");
                    });
                }
                //IF MESSAGES
                if(typeof data['message'] !== 'undefined') {
                    //APPEND MESSAGES TO MESSAGE
                    $.each( data['message'], function( index,data) {
                        message += (data + "\n");
                    });
                }

                //IF CONSOLE MESSAGES
                if(typeof data['console'] !== 'undefined') {
                    //APPEND CONSOLE MESSAGES TO MESSAGE
                    $.each( data['console'], function( index,data) {
                        consolemessage += (data + "\n");
                    });
                }
                //IF SUCCESS SENT FROM SERVER
                if(typeof data['success'] !== 'undefined') {
                    //CLEAR FORM
                    $('.clubregister input[type="text"], .clubregister textarea').val('');
                }
                alert(message);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code and that you don't have uncommented console.log ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in comments, I suspect you have an uncommented call to `console.log` somewhere.

This is a frequent problem on IE as the console object isn't available when the developer tools aren't open.

The common workaround is to build a dummy object to replace it when it's not available :

```
if (!window.console) {
    var names = ["log", "debug", "info", "warn", "error", "assert", "dir", "dirxml",
    "group", "groupEnd", "time", "timeEnd", "count", "trace", "profile", "profileEnd"];
    window.console = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
        window.console[names[i]] = function() {};
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure where to insert this in the code. I tried in the console section and it did not work.

Comment: Put it at the start of your script, before anything else.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks so much. This worked perfectly. Such a good feeling to get something working! Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 3):

Internet explorer exposes the `console` object only when the developer tools are active (e.g., pressing F12).

If the developers tools are hidden, then calling `console.log` will throw an exception, hence, the javascript code will break.

Comment: So is there a solution to getting the form not to break with out having the console up?

Comment: you could make a mock console object if it's undefined.
if (!window.console) window.console = {log:function() {}}

Comment: Where would I put this in my javascript?