# Why my code doesn't work on Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why my code doesn't work on Internet Explorer:

[image]

64 line start here:

```
$(function () {
    $('#id_laufzeit_bis').datepicker().on('changeDate', recalculate_deadline);
    $('#id_kuendigungsfrist').change(recalculate_deadline);
    $('#id_kuendigungsfrist_type').change(recalculate_deadline);

    $('#id_kuendigung_moeglichbis').change(check_reminder_date);
    $('#id_erinnerung_am').datepicker().on('hide', check_reminder_date);

    //$('#id_vertrag_verlaengerung').change(recalculate_deadline);
    //$('#id_vertrag_verlaengerung_type').change(recalculate_deadline);
});
```

Full code here: http://wklej.org/hash/a8884a307f3/

Comment: Any chance of a JFiddler with complete code. eg, where is recalculate_time initialized?

Comment: Do u have a reference for jquery ?

Comment: "Which one is Line 64? - first - > $(function () {

Comment: You probably don't have jQuery loaded..

Comment: @Mahmoud What exactly do you mean? In other browsers work

Comment: He means to ask: have you included jQuery file?

Comment: And ... Is this really IE5?

Comment: Ok then can you post your complete javascript code?

Comment: @Hanky Panky ㇱ I added full code

Comment: @user1966421 which version of IE ??

Comment: Something is off here, this is not a usual IE error message. IE does not throw WSH errors.

Comment: Internet Explorer 8/9 on windows 7

Comment: @dualed So where do I find the error? :)

Comment: This error is displeyed when I visited: www.mysite.com/static/js/my.file.js in other browsers this link displayed js code

Comment: Of course it is displayed then. But why would you open the .js file in your browser directly?

Comment: My features do not work on IE and was looking for a reason. Maybe IE can not load my js file

Comment: If you open a JavaScript (`.js`) file directly in Internet Explorer, it is run at a (somewhat restricted) system level on Windows Scripting Host (WSH) it does not have any link to your site then (and so jQuery is missing and this error is thrown). Press [F12] to debug on Internet Explorer.

Comment: If I press F12 my js function work fine, without F12 doesn't work

Comment: You have to reload after pressing F12

Answer (score 3):

If you open a JavaScript (`.js`) file directly in Internet Explorer, it is run at a (somewhat restricted) system level on **Windows Script(ing) Host** (WSH) it does not have any link to your HTML site at this point and so jQuery is missing and this error is thrown.

- Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the Web Developer tools on Internet Explorer. Then reload your site again.

As a web developer you may also want to always enable showing scripting errors without the developer console:

- In the **Advanced** tab of the **Internet Options** dialog, there is a checkbox to enable displaying of scripting errors.

Comment: Thanks, but If I press F12 and refresh the page all js/jquery functions works. If I closed F12 (web developer tools) my js/jQ function still doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Showing or hiding the devtools should not change how the JavaScript is evaluated. However, like I suggested, you can enable displaying of scripting errors to make sure. Then you can close the devtools and reload to see if there is a scripting error (it's a quite visible popup). If there is none and you can't figure it out you should probably open a new question where you can explain what exactly "does not work"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708841/form-works-in-internet-explorer-only-when-i-hit-f12-to-bring-up-console  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602277/ie-runs-javascript-only-after-pressing-f12

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an issue with jquery-ui library. It seems that you are trying to access the datepicker method before it has been defined and is available.

I made this piece of code working on IE 8 by using document.ready as

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
 $('#id_laufzeit_bis').datepicker().on('changeDate', recalculate_deadline);
});
```

See full working page @ http://jsfiddle.net/n7fMK/1/

Hope this helps.